# React Multiple Checkboxes are not visible as selected after change

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes.
Checkbox is not visible as selected even after the `value` has been changed.

Below is my code: -

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const CheckboxComponent = () => {
  const [checkedList, setCheckedList] = useState([
    { id: 1, label: "First", isCheck: false },
    { id: 2, label: "Second", isCheck: true }
  ]);

  const handleCheck = (e, index) => {
    checkedList[index]["isCheck"] = e.target.checked;
    setCheckedList(checkedList);
    console.log(checkedList);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {checkedList.map((c, index) => (
        <div>
          <input
            id={c.id}
            type="checkbox"
            checked={c.isCheck}
            onChange={e => handleCheck(e, index)}
          />
          <label htmlFor={c.id}>{c.label}</label>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

render(<CheckboxComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I was working fine for a simple checkbox outside the loop.
I am not sure where is the problem.

Here is the link - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multiple-checkboxes-sczhy?file=/src/index.js:0-848

Comment: your `checklist` state is not changed, so react doesn't re-render in this case

Comment: Im doing setCheckedList(checkedList). Why it is not reflecting my changes ?

Comment: the reference to that array is still the same, the only things changed is its property

Answer (score 1):

Cause you pass an array to the state, so if you want your react component re-render, you must let the react know that your state change. On your `handleCheck`, you only change property of an value in that array so the reference is not changed.

The `handleCheck` function should be look like this

```js
  const handleCheck = (e, index) => {
    const newCheckList = [...checkedList];
    newCheckList[index]["isCheck"] = e.target.checked;
    setCheckedList(newCheckList);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
const handleCheck = (e, index) => {
    setCheckedList(prevState => {
        const nextState = prevState.slice()
        nextState[index]["isCheck"] = e.target.checked;
        return nextState
    });
};
```

Since `checkedList` is an array, (considered as object and handled as such), changing a property won't change the array itself. So React can know that something changed.